# How to post a local notification prior to 5 minutes before the actual time of the remainder in iOS program?

Tags: ios, reminders

I've created a reminder in my app, I want the remainder to be notified before 5 minutes of its actual time. If yes, is there any default available for doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For this you can add two reminders, one for actual time and other 5 minutes before the actual time. Now you can do different things on receiving both reminders..

Answer (score 1):

you can remove 5 min by creating new date from your date by

```
NSDate *fiveMinutesBeforeDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-60*5 sinceDate:dateFromFirstString];
```

and create local notification by following cate and set this date to firedate of local notification

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = fiveMinutesBeforeDate;
localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Alert Fired at %@", fiveMinutesBeforeDate];
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```